# Runtime error '52' Bad filename or number with Dir$ function

Tags: vba, excel

I need to check if a chrome.exe file exists, and if so, open the browser. I'm getting

> Runtime error '52' Bad filename or number

On the first `If` check. Why is that?

```
Sub openChrome()
    Dim chromePath32
    Dim chromePath64
    Dim chromePathUser
    Dim current_user

    chromePath32 = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
    chromePath64 = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
    current_user = (Environ$("Username"))
    chromePathUser = """c:\users\" & current_user & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe"""

    If Dir$(chromePath32) <> "" Then '<-----error here
        Shell (chromePath32 & " -url http:google.co.nz")
    ElseIf Dir$(chromePath64) <> "" Then
        Shell (chromePath64 & " -url http:google.co.nz")
    ElseIf Dir$(chromePathUser) <> "" Then
        Shell (chromePathUser & " -url http:google.co.nz")
    Else
        MsgBox "Chrome installation not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your quotes around the directories - they are not needed in the `Dir` command:

```
chromePath32 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
chromePath64 = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
current_user = (Environ$("Username"))
chromePathUser = "c:\users\" & current_user & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe"
```

You **may** need them in the `Shell` command, although I just tried on a 32-bit version and it worked without them:

```
If Dir$(chromePath32) <> "" Then
    Shell """" & chromePath32 & """ -url http:google.co.nz"
ElseIf Dir$(chromePath64) <> "" Then
    Shell """" & chromePath64 & """ -url http:google.co.nz"
ElseIf Dir$(chromePathUser) <> "" Then
    Shell """" & chromePathUser & """ -url http:google.co.nz"
Else
    MsgBox "Chrome installation not found"
    Exit Sub
End If
```